# Good player ship for anti-capital ship warfare

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

The Hyperion Vanguard in Albion Prelude seems to have been declawed somewhat compared to the way it was in Reunion and Terran Conflict (less shields, capitals have significantly more hull, super-heavy capitals introduced, et cetera), so I am looking for a ship that will be able to destroy enemy M2 destroyers as well as M1 carriers and their fighter wings.

What would be a good ship and loadout for this purpose? My main concerns are:

1. Ability to kill an enemy capital ship quickly. This will likely depend on available weapon mounts, total weapon energy, weapon generator and number of guns that can be brought to bear on a target, ideally front, top/bottom and left/right turrets.
2. Ability to survive enemy capital ship fire. Likely depends on ship profile, shields and maneuverability - a slender Split Python will avoid a great deal of projectiles that would hit a Boron Megalodon.
3. Ability to survive enemy fighter fire. This will likely depend on speed, maneuverability, profile and active defenses.
4. Average downtime between capital ship kills. This will likely depend on type of shields equipped (5x200MJ shields will recharge faster than 1x1GJ shield) shield generators (unless all ships have enough shield generator output to recharge shields at their maximum rate), although "venting" shields by ejecting and picking them up is an option for an otherwise excellent ship.
5. Sustainability. Having to build a missile complex and resupply at it after every 2nd capital killed can get old quickly.

Comment: the ugly duckling, i.e. boreas is still the best unless you have a huge supply of M7M missiles, in which case any one of them will do :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have much success in my Split Tiger.  IBL on the right turret (x2), PALC on the left (dropped by the various Qs and Carracks I've tangled with), Flak Artillery on the other turrets.

My Main cannons are 2x IBL, 6x CIG.

I find myself quickly kiting fighter swarms when going up against an M1, but M2s are slow moving easy kills (though it does take a while to whittle down)

Comment: Well, Split ships **are** the best. Any particular strategy to using it?

Comment: With the above weapon config, I make a strong run with frontal weapons at capital ships, then stay ~3km away from my target in a wide circling fashion and let the right side IBLs do their job.  This is super effective against Terrans, since their capital weapon projectiles move so slowly.  they have a hard time tracking the speed of my Tiger.  The other turrets keep fighters and missiles off me while I work on the capitals.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Kyoto for convenient Xenon sector sweeps with almost no downtimes. Although it's big, it is quite agile because of good turn rates. Opening up with charged PSP's alpha strike it one-shots those annoying Q's and eats major part of bigger guys' shields. Terran's trademark slim profile helps a lot in preserving your shields and thus reducing downtimes. The most important part is being able to dock 6 M6's, so I can engage in my Hyperion V with PBGs if fighter swarms get too annoying. Most of the time my M6's are doing "collect wares in sector".

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Griffon seems quite nice. You deploy your own fleet of drones or small detachment of fighters and when the capital ship is distracted just step in and finish the job with slightly inferior weaponry. Shame it can't use some heavier weaponry, but flaks and cig's are quite decent for general population. Plus it is possible to retrieve (via autodock) the fleet'o'drones if you have hangar bay... which you do. Not sure if collision avoidance is still a nuisance as it used to be before the ap patches. To the point where you had to leave oos for drones to dock.